# Linux Crontab Python script error: "Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified"

Tags: python, selenium, cron, display, xlib

let me explain the problem in detail:
I have a Windows 10 desktop, from which i connect via RDP (same LAN) to a laptop running Kali Linux 2022.3.

On this laptop, i have Conda and Spyder for developing some webscraping Python scripts.
I developed a web scraping script that simulate a user navigate to a site, logging in, upload a document and log out (this is to iterate some real-work stuff).

In my script i use selenium and pyautogui.

In my testing process:

1. from desktop i RDP to laptop
2. from laptop (i login with root) i open spyder
3. i run the script (chromedriver in headless mode, altough i tested it also in viewable mode).
4. everythings run just fine. it open the browser, login, upload the file and logout. (also in headless mode the test succeed, i see no browser BUT i have a mail confirmation that the script ran successfuly).

The problem comes when i try to schedule the script via crontab.

I made a scraper.sh with:
/path_to_python/ /root/path_to_script.py >> /root/out_err.txt 2>&1

And then, in crontab i put the line (i want the script to run at 15 every 2 day):
00 15 */2 * * /root/scraper.sh

I wait connected to the laptop until the script fires, and of course the script RUN, but does nothing. So i go to the the out_err file, and i find:

```
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified\n'
```

I am stuck at this point, where my knowledge fail me ;-)
Can anyone help? Thank You very much.
David